# How is an elasticsearch query executed at the OS level?

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I am particularly curious about the entire life cycle from the time clients hits a query to what happens on each node of the cluster wrt that query to the time client is served the ranked results.

Comment: I have basic awareness of inverted indices, shards, nodes, cluster but I am having tough time visualising the whole process on how the OS is spurred to action when an ES query is hit?
execution threads, CPU intensive vs I/O intensive,  
 concurrency,  performance bottlenecks. 
Any pointers to relevant literature will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

while it's written for previous versions of Elasticsearch, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html goes into this in varying places and the core concepts are still the same

we don't really document down to the OS level though